# firebase transactions after restart with persistence enabled

Tags: firebase

I'm getting the following message from firebase:
runTransactionBlock: usage detected while persistence is enabled. Please be aware that transactions *will not* be persisted across app restarts.

So what exactly happens after the app restarts?  Do the updates in my local database get overwritten due to a sync event from the main database?  Something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transactions are not persisted to disk. So when you app is restarted, none of your transactions will be sent to the server.

After regaining connectivity, your local cache will contain the data from the server.

Comment: OK.  Before I mark your response as answered - I just want to make sure I understand.  If a user is working off-line, they won't see the effect of their updates (say on a tableview) until they re-establish connectivity.  And if their device powers down before connectivity is established they lose all their work?  Is that right?

Comment: If you want the user to be able to work while they are not connected to the server and have disk persistence so that they can stop/restart the app, don't use transactions.

Comment: I'm sorry @FrankvanPuffelen, but can you clarify the nature of persistence? In reading the guide it appears that setting values will write to the firebase in the cloud. https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html